# How to enable pro features in In-App purchase if purchase is successful

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to implement the in-App purchase of non-consumable goods. I have implemented the sample code of TROY “In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough” http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/.I am getting the product information from the server.I am also able to make the purchase that product.I am implementing this in sand box environment.I also get a call back whether the purchase is successful or not.

The problem i am facing is that when i debug the code , none of the methods in the InAppPurchaseManager are being invoked except
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response

So i am not able to put the code in which i want to enable the pro features if the purchase is successful.

Thanks

Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my problem

The -loadStore method has to be invoked right after invoking the -purchaseProUpgrade method is called from the class in which we are implementing th inApp purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on my iPhone4.  After searching for answers I decided to just go to SETTINGS to see what I needed to change.  I clicked RESTRICTIONS and found that all restrictions were enabled.  I DISABLED the restrictions [had to enter my passcode] and like magic, it worked!  I was immediately able to make an in-app purchase. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that this was really the issue that Aditya had.  It seems as though you were answering "Has any ever had trouble making in-app purchases on their iPhone?".  However, the question was more related to: "I'm writing software to make in-app purchases for an iPhone and I need help finding the correct method to code".